# For Loop Not updating values

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to code a trend following loop to update a dataframe as I go.  My account value specifically is not changing.

```
import numpy as np
from get_data import get_data
import pandas as pd
def trend_follow(start_date, end_date, account=50000, big_dollar_value=5):
    df = get_data(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
    df['buy_and_hold'] = 1
    df['position'] = 0
    df['qty'] = 0
    df['account'] = account
    df['unit'] = np.floor((.01 * df['account']) / (big_dollar_value * df['atr_15']))
    df['pyramid_stop'] = (df['unit']*4)
    df['stop_loss'] = df['account']*.01
    account_ = account

    for i, row in df.iterrows():

        # find a short position
        if row['position'] == 0 and row['qty'] == 0 and row['premarket'] == 0 and row['postmarket'] == 0:
            if row['low'] <= row['low_mark']:
                qty = row['unit']
                df.at[i, 'qty'] = qty
                position_ = -1
                df.at[i, 'position'] = position_
                account_ += (row['position'] * (row['account'] * (row['qty'] * row['log_return'])))
                df.at[i, 'account'] = account_

        # in the short position....let it ride
        elif row['position'] == -1 and row['qty'] > 0:
            if (row['account'] > (row['account'] - row['stop_loss'])) and (row['adjusted_close'] < row['n_point_five']):
                qty = qty
                position_ = -1
                df.at[i, 'position'] = position_
                df.at[i, 'qty'] = qty
                account_ += (row['position'] * (row['account'] * (row['qty'] * row['log_return'])))
                df.at[i, 'account'] = account_
```

I though updating account_ in the loop would update account_ outside of the loop at the top and I could carry that through. It's not doing that however.

Below is some sample data:

```
df_dict = {'datetime': ['2018-12-13 16:10:00', '2018-12-13 16:15:00', '2018-12-14 09:35:00', '2018-12-14 09:40:00', '2018-12-14 09:45:00', '2018-12-14 09:50:00', '2018-12-14 09:55:00', '2018-12-14 10:00:00', '2018-12-14 10:05:00', '2018-12-14 10:10:00', '2018-12-14 10:15:00', '2018-12-14 10:20:00', '2018-12-14 10:25:00', '2018-12-14 10:30:00', '2018-12-14 10:35:00', '2018-12-14 10:40:00', '2018-12-14 10:45:00', '2018-12-14 10:50:00'],
       'open': [2606.25, 2605.75, 2584.0, 2581.5, 2584.0, 2587.25, 2588.25, 2589.0, 2590.25, 2592.0, 2590.0, 2589.25, 2591.0, 2589.5, 2584.25, 2578.25, 2584.0, 2583.0],
       'high': [2606.75, 2606.75, 2584.5, 2584.0, 2587.25, 2590.75, 2589.25, 2592.25, 2592.25, 2592.0, 2590.25, 2594.25, 2592.5, 2591.0, 2584.25, 2584.75, 2585.5, 2588.5],
       'low': [2605.0, 2601.75, 2580.0, 2579.5, 2582.25, 2586.25, 2585.0, 2587.25, 2589.0, 2587.5, 2587.25, 2588.75, 2588.75, 2584.0, 2577.75, 2577.5, 2582.5, 2581.5],
       'adjusted_close': [2605.75, 2602.0, 2581.75, 2584.0, 2587.25, 2588.25, 2589.0, 2590.25, 2591.75, 2590.0, 2589.25, 2591.0, 2589.5, 2584.0, 2578.25, 2584.25, 2583.0, 2587.0],
       'low_mark': [2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0, 2583.0],
       'atr_15': [26.19206349,26.19206349,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,
                  26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,26.24861386,
                  26.24861386]
       'premarket': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'postmarket': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'log_return': [-0.000191865,-0.001440162,-0.007812917,0.000871122,0.00125695,0.000386436,0.000289729,0.000482695,
                      0.000578927,-0.000675448,-0.000289617,0.000675643,-0.000579095,-0.002126221,-0.002227712,0.002324456,
                      -0.000483816,0.001547389]
       'expected_output': [50000.00,50000.00,51171.94,51038.21,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75
                           ,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75,50845.75,51185.56,50828.62,50902.40,50666.10]
```

]}

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

My account column is not changing.  It stays at the starting value - 50000.

When the position changes from 0 to -1, I expect

Comment: Can you please include your expected output? What should the value of `account_` be after your loop and what do you want to do with this value?

Comment: Also, we can't run your code as is. What is `df['atr_15']`?

Comment: Are you returning `account_` from this function and checking the value there? Are you printing `account_` inside the function, but after the `for` loop? Where are you checking the value to tell that it's incorrect in this code?

Comment: added expected out put to data dictionary

Comment: @JNevill.  The account_ is not updating.  My question is trying to figure out why it's not updating. I printed after the first account_ assignment and after the for-loop.

Comment: atr_15 added @not_speshal

Comment: I suggest you add `print(account_)` to make sure it's what you think it is.